# sequelize return association of manually defined join table

Tags: database, postgresql, sequelize.js, model-associations

I'm using Sequelize with Postgres. Two of my tables (`estimatorList` and `subcontractor`)  are joined by a manually defined table (`estimatorSubsList`).

```
db.subcontractor.belongsToMany(db.estimatorList, { through: db.estimatorSubsList });
db.estimatorList.belongsToMany(db.subcontractor, { through: db.estimatorSubsList });
```

`estimatorSubsList` has an id and other fields but it is also associated to `contact` via

```
db.contact.hasMany(db.estimatorSubsList);
```

When I query the database for `estimatorList` with a particular id and return the `subcontractor` (and tables associated with subcontractor) associated with this -

```
db.estimatorList.findById(estimatorListId, {include:  [ { 
            model: db.subcontractor, 
            include: [  db.location, etc, etc ]
     }
    ]} )
```

It returns all the correct information. It also automatically returns `estimatorSubsList` with the `contactId` inside each `subcontractor` object. EG:

```
estimatorSubsList: 
{ contactId: 1
  createdAt: ""
  estimatorListId: 1
  id:2
  otherFields:false
  subcontractorId: 2
  updatedAt:"" 
}
```

My question is, is it possible to get not only the contactId, but the whole contact record itself? I'm unsure how to change the default information being returned or if that is even possible. I've tried including the `estimatorSubsList` model and including `contact` from that, but it doesn't like me trying to include `estimatorSubsList` at all.

Cheers all

Comment: You can nest includes and modify the attributes with the attributes option. It's all documented

Comment: Hi @felixfbecker,
I've been through the documentation over the past few days and can't seem to find a solution. Is there a heading I should specifically look into? I understand the nesting, but I don't know how to change what is automatically being returned ie. the json above, when I query estimatorList. I don't call estimatorSubsList itself but its being returned with Subcontractors. I'd like to include contact in that part of the return.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Please help @felixfbecker , I still cannot find a solution. I want to return db.contact that is associated with my through table - db.estimatorSubsList. Struggling!

I see how I can change attributes using **through** , but I still cant find how to return the db.contacts model associated with my through/join table.

Comment: Sure, you can include models with `include` - where exactly is your problem?

Comment: Hey @felixfbecker , I cant seem to include anything that is connected off the through/join. I can access attributes using `through` but I cant access any model that's associated to through. Im trying to get something like this to work.
`db.estimatorList.findAll({
        where: where,
        include:  [ { 
                model: db.subcontractor,
                include: [db.otherStuff],
                through: {
                    attributes: ['a', etc.],
                    include: [db.contact] 
                    }       
                 }
                ]})`
Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible for a through relation table to have associations. Instead, you should model it as a separate model and include it as such:

```
EstimatorList.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: EstimatorSubsList,
    include: [Contact, Subcontractor]
  }]
})
```

Make sure you have all associations set up in both directions.

Comment: Thankyou! Headache resolved! I did as you said and restructured my models and associations and used nested includes. Thanks again @felixfbecker